# shortcut for expanding datasheet in access 2003?

Tags: ms-access

when i open a datasheet/table in access, the field names are normally partially covered by the neighboring rows. Is there any shortcut, which can be used to expand all of them at one shot?

Comment: Surely this is a question for SuperUser not StackOverflow...I don't see any programming component at all.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unaware of any "shortcut" or code to automatically expand the width on each column. However, the ColumnWidth property is both read and write.

I usually save the column width when the user closes the form. I save the values of each column to a settings file. Then when the user loads the form I load in those settings.

Here's some sample code to get the value of the ColumnWidth property for each control:

```
Dim ictl as Integer
Dim ctl as Control
For ictl = 0 To Me.Controls.Count - 1
    Set ctl = Me.Controls(ictl)
    MsgBox ctl.Name & "=" & ctl.ColumnWidth
Next ictl
```

Answer (score 0):

You can select all the columns by dragging the mouse over the relevant column names (ctrl-A and the top left grey square will not work) and then choose Format->Column Width->Best Fit or enter a value. This is not quite satisfactory, because it will only be "best fit" for currently displayed rows, in other words, if there is a very wide cell further down the page, it still will not display fully, however, it should suit quite well for column (field) names.